# GCP - Use CLI to list version of package (Ops Agent) on all Compute Engines in all Projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-monitoring

Is there some way how to list all Compute Engines in all projects and their version of OpsAgent installed on them? We have a lot of projects and VMs and I need to make a list of VMs with old OpsAgent version.

Comment: It's possible but you may need to ssh to every instance.

Answer (score 0):

Using the gcloud cli commands is not possible.
You may however see the agent installed whether it is the Legacy agent or the newer Ops Agent using the Cloud Monitoring > Dashboards > VM Instances > Agent column.

[image]

You can also take a look at this documentation on [Managing the agents using automation tools](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/ops-agent/fleet-installation)